# Why does c++ not print out 2/3 as 0.666667?

Tags: c++

I wrote

```
double r = 2/3;
cout << "r = " << r << endl;
```

Then it returns

```
r = 0
```

I would like it to show that r = 0.666667 or something like that instead of a 0. Especially I need to use that r = 2/3 to do calculation in my algorithm. How can I fix that?

Comment: Many other questioners have already been told this answer, I'm surprised you didn't see them when you searched before asking, I can only assume the search engine is broken :-) `2 / 3` is *integer* division because the components are integers. Make one of them floating point and you'll get better results: `2.0/3`.

Comment: [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777053/how-to-convert-integer-to-double-implicitly)

Answer (score 2):

Because both `2` and `3` are literals of type `int`, and integer division yields an integer result in C++. What you did is perform integer division first, then promote the integer result to `double`.

Instead, you want to cast at least one of the operands to `float` or `double` (a fractional floating point-type), then the other operand will be promoted to the same type and the resulting value will also be `float` or `double`.

Either of these will work:
`double r = 2.0/3.0;`
`double r = 2.0/3;`
`double r = 2/3.0;`