# C++ wrong calculation and no percentage showing

Tags: c++

The calculation is only right in a and c, it is very wrong on b and c is off by 1. And the percentage only shows zero. Although the formulas is the same I can't figure out why the two is wrong, And why the percentage only shows zero and doesn't follow my formula.

Here the output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nvct.png)

And here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main(){
    string candidate[4];
    int a[5], b[5], c[5], d[5];//precint
    int at,bt,ct,dt;
    int ap, bp, cp, dp;
    int total;
    int choice;
    char yesNo;
    int i;
    
    do{ 
    cout<<"[1] Enter candidates names and votes"<<endl;
    cout<<"[2] Show Tally"<<endl;
    cout<<"[3] Exit"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter a choice: ";
    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice){
        case(1):
    
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        cout<<"Enter candidate names: ";
        cin>>candidate[i];}
        
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<"Candidate "<<candidate[0]<<" precinct "<<i+1<<" votes: ";
        cin>>a[i];
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<"Candidate "<<candidate[1]<<" precinct "<<i+1<<" votes: ";
        cin>>b[i];
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<"Candidate "<<candidate[2]<<" precinct "<<i+1<<" votes: ";
        cin>>c[i];
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<"Candidate "<<candidate[3]<<" precinct "<<i+1<<" votes: ";
        cin>>d[i];
        }
        
        break;
        case(2):
            cout<<"Precinct\t"<<candidate[0]<<"\t\t"<<candidate[1]<<"\t\t"<<candidate[2]<<"\t\t"<<candidate[3]<<endl;
            
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ //for displaying the tally
                cout<<i+1<<"\t\t"<<a[i]<<"\t\t"<<b[i]<<"\t\t"<<c[i]<<"\t\t"<<d[i]<<endl;
            }
            cout<<endl;
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ //for the total votes
                at=at+a[i];
                bt=bt+b[i];
                ct=ct+c[i];
                dt=dt+d[i];
                                
            }
            total=at+bt+ct+dt;  //for the percent
            ap=(at/total)*100;
            bp=(bt/total)*100;
            cp=(ct/total)*100;
            dp=(dt/total)*100;
            
            cout<<"Candidate "<<candidate[0]<<" total votes and percentage: "<<at<<" votes. "<<ap<<"%"<<endl;
            cout<<"Candidate "<<candidate[1]<<" total votes and percentage: "<<bt<<" votes. "<<ap<<"%"<<endl;
            cout<<"Candidate "<<candidate[2]<<" total votes and percentage: "<<ct<<" votes. "<<ap<<"%"<<endl;
            cout<<"Candidate "<<candidate[3]<<" total votes and percentage: "<<dt<<" votes. "<<ap<<"%"<<endl;
            
            
        break;
        }
        cout<<"Do you want to continue(Y/N): ";
        cin>>yesNo;
    }while (yesNo == 'y' || yesNo == 'Y');
        cout<<"Thank You!";
    

    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is because you are using integer math. If you are dividing two integers, the result is an integer. You want something like `static_cast<double>(at)/(total)` instead, to explicitly tell the compiler to do floating point math.

For example `1/2 = 0` but `1.0/2.0 = 0.5`

Comment: Great, it also solves the wrong addition, though i dont understand why.

Comment: Maybe this will help to clear things up a bit more https://stackoverflow.com/q/9455271/16326708

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double instead of int to represent the variables that are used to store the percentages.
Initialize the variables that are used to store the totals.

You can find more about double conversion here. [How to convert integer to double implicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777053/how-to-convert-integer-to-double-implicitly)

And you are printing the same percentage value i.e. **ap** for all the candidates.

```
int at = 0, bt = 0, ct = 0, dt = 0;
double ap, bp, cp, dp;

//Rest of the code

ap = ((double)at / total) * 100;
bp = ((double)bt / total) * 100;
cp = ((double)ct / total) * 100;
dp = ((double)dt / total) * 100;
```